# Ayuda con variables en PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, session

Tengo variables que se obtienen las obtengo de una pagina, con el GET las saco del input type text, y despues creo variable session para tener una variable global, pero al momento de llevarla a otra pagina me marca que no existe.

Con esto quiero llenar una tabla en SQL, pero las variables de cantidad y precio son las que se me estan complicando debido a que las estoy dando paginas antes mientras las otras(Nombre,ID,etc) las doy solo una pagina antes mediante un form.

PAGINA DONDE SE CREA:

```
input type="color" name="color" />
<p>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form action="Registro.php" >
CANTIDAD <input type="text" name="cantidad"  />

</B></I></font></font> </p> 
</th>
<th width="385">
<input type="submit" name="Agregar1" value="AGREGAR" /></form>
</th>
</table> 
</div>
<br />
<br />
</div>

<div id="cinco">
<table width="1056">
<th width="312"> 
<img src="p3.jpg"  width="200" height="200"/>
</th>
<th width="343">
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<font face="arial"> <font color="#FFFFFF"> <I> <B> COLOR FAVORITO </B></I></font></font>
<input type="color" name="color" />
<p>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<form action="Registro.php" method="post">
CANTIDAD <input type="text" name="Cantidad"  />
</B></I></font></font> </p> 
</th>
<th width="385">
<input type="submit" name="Agregar2" value="AGREGAR" /></form>

</th>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<br />
</div>

<div id="seis">
<table width="1056">
<th width="312"> 
<img src="imagen3.jpg"  width="200" height="200"/>
</th>
<th width="343">
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<font face="arial"> <font color="#FFFFFF"> <I> <B> COLOR FAVORITO </B></I></font></font>
<input type="color" name="color" />
<p>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form action="Registro.php" method="post">
CANTIDAD <input type="text" name="cantidad"  />

</B></I></font></font> </p> 
</th>
<th width="385">

<input type="submit" name="Agregar3" value="AGREGAR" /></form>
</th>
</table> 
<br />

<br />
<br />
</div>

</body>


<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
   $_SESSION['cantidad']=($_GET['cantidad']);
  if(isset($_POST['Agregar1']))
  {
   $_SESSION['precio']=500;
  }
   if(isset($_POST['Agregar1']))
   $_SESSION['precio']=600;
   if(isset($_POST['Agregar1']))
   $_SESSION['precio']=200;
?>
```

PAGINA DONDE LA RECIBE:

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
   include("Conexion.php"); 

   $id=$_GET['Id'];
   $nombre=$_GET['Nombre'];
   $cantidad=$_SESSION['cantidad'];
   $apellido=$_GET['Apellido']; 
   $email=$_GET['Email']; 
   $telefono=$_GET['Telefono']; 
   $pais=$_GET['Pais']; 
   $ciudad=$_GET['Ciudad']; 
   $precio=$_SESSION['precio'];

   $total=$precio*$cantidad;

   if($total<1500)
   {
    $ttotal=$total;   
   }
   else
   {
    $ttotal=$total+400;   
   }



   $direccion=$_GET['Direccion']; 
   $insertar = "insert into Tienda (ID_Compra,Cantidad,Nombre,Apellido,Email,Telefono,Pais,Ciudad,Direccion,Total) 
                values ('$id','$nombre','$cantidad','$apellido','$email','$telefono','$pais','$ciudad','$direccion','$ttotal)";
```

Comment: ¿El único error que marca es que no existe o te dice algo más? ¿Qué te aparece si imprimes el arreglo $_SESSION con var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y finalmente lo solucioné enviándolo mediante Cookies en lugar de enviarlas como Session.
En tu caso sería añadir en el origen: `setcookie("cantidad", $valor_cantidad, time()+3600*24*30, '/');` y luego en donde la recibe: `$cantidad = $_COOKIE['cantidad'];`